# Break point in debug mode is not working with jhipster

Tags: java, breakpoints, jhipster

I am working on **jhipster Release 0.7.0** and used spring STS to run project with **tomcat7**.

But i an not able to access `Break point` on debug mode . Debugger skip that point and open Debug perspective.

Please help to Break point in debug mode is not working with **jHipster**

Answer (score 4):

- Right click on your "Application" class, you should be able to run/debug it.
- Select "Debug", of course :-)
- To set a breakpoint, just click on the left of line you are interested in, it should display a red dot. When this code is executed, you should enter debug mode!

Comment: Yes i know that but it is not working. Debugger skip that point and open Debug perspective

Comment: Sorry for down-voting, it actually worked for me, don't know how though, can't up-vote now, the answer need do be edited it says.

Answer (score -1):

Run mvn debug, you should be "Run Configurations" select "Source" tab . click "add" select your Project .
"Apply"-"Dubug" isok!