# How to debug JHipster in Eclipse?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, maven, debugging, jhipster

I'm new on using JHipster . I'm having trouble debugging in Eclipse IDE on JHipster 5.x (springboot and angular) . I use maven to build the project

So I'm looking for a tutorial to debug with eclipse.

Comment: Nothing specific to JHipster, at least for debugging the java backend, it's the same as for any Spring Boot app. And for the angular part, I don't know in Eclipse but there are plenty of examples using VS Code and Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can enable spring-boot JVM to run in debug mode with passing to maven:

```
-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -DskipTests -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

to maven

Afterwards run a Eclipse Remote Java Application Debugging with Attaching to this process.

A good tutorial can be found here: https://jhipster.xenovation.com/debugging-jhipster-with-eclipse/

Comment: Thank you for this link, I will test this tutorial.

Comment: you are welcome to ask if something is unclear